# Why do I get the "extra data after last expected column' when importing .csv into my database?

Tags: postgresql, csv

Ok, I've managed to solve the problem. I had comas on the problematic lines which was causing the script to not run. I had to go through each one to fix it, but it worked in the end. Thanks

I created a table using

```
CREATE TABLE customers_transfer
(
  customer text,
  phone text,
  alt_phone text,
  fax text,
  street1 text,
  street2 text,
  city text,
  state text,
  zip text,
  email text,      
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE

);
```

and I have a .csv file that matches it. But when I try running `COPY customers_transfer FROM 'C:/customer_transfer.csv' DELIMITER ','` I get this error. I've tried adding a single ',' to every last line but it still happens.

```
Access America Transport,423.821.8044,,423.678.7782,"2515 East 43rd St, Suite B",,Chattanooga,TN,37407,invoices@accessamericatransport.com
```

Comment: Show a sample of the file's lines where the error occurs

Comment: Have you tried removing the comma from the last column `email text`?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto without adding any commas at the end, I the error at line 10 `Access America Transport,423.821.8044,,423.678.7782,"2515 East 43rd St, Suite B",,Chattanooga,TN,37407,invoices@accessamericatransport.com`

Comment: @JustinC It doesn't have any commas at the end by default. I just added one to see if it will help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it should be

```
COPY customers_transfer FROM 'C:/customer_transfer.csv' CSV
```

the DELIMITER ',' makes it split the text "2515 East 43rd St, Suite B" into two columns

Comment: I'm using libreoffice and I just can't get it to use any other delimiter. any advice? I have to do this quite often, and every time I end up deleting the extra ',' line by line

Comment: can you show me a few examples of the good lines, bad lines and how you are copying

Comment: ahnks @Bruno its useful for show ",,,,,," error but why this error is hapen